# Where could I find more examples of using PetitParser?

Tags: parsing, smalltalk, pharo, visualworks, petitparser

I'm looking for additional examples of using PetitParser beyond PPArithmeticParser and PPLambdaParser that are provided in the tests package and a couple of blog posts by Lukas? If anyone's willing to share theirs, it would be much appreciated.

Updated: https://github.com/NicolasPetton/jtalk/blob/master/st/parser.st
Updated: https://github.com/dmatveev/waste/blob/master/wastex.st

Keep 'em coming!

Comment: Well, you have gotten what you expected, namely, answers supported by facts, references and expertise. Also, no debate, arguments, polling or extended discussions were originated. As a result, the reasons given for closing this question have no footing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the official PetitParser [code repository](http://source.lukas-renggli.ch/petit/), there are many grammars ready to download:

- PetitCSV
- PetitJson (well tested, builds Smalltalk objects)
- PetitMSE
- PetitManifestMf
- PetitRegex
- PetitSQL
- PetitSmalltalk (well tested, can be used as a replacement for the refactoring engine parser)
- PetitXml (well tested)

Additionally you find various PetitParser grammars on [SqueakSource](http://www.squeaksource.com). Just search for 'PetitParser' as a keyword and you find more or less complete grammars for Java, JavaScript, Ada, SQL, and some others.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of small nice examples on [PetitParsers Google+ site](https://plus.google.com/106183196107092257653).

- Quickly extract all JavaDoc comments from a file
- Parse 'self', but not variables like 'selfish' or 'selfism'
- A PetitParser grammar that only accepts an even number of a's and b's
- Parse a non context-free language
- Parse floating point numbers
- Parse nestable Haskell comments
- ...

Comment: It's sad that this was on the killed-by-Google G+ social media.  Did anyone save it?